# How to set border color and width of CCLabelTTF text in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to set border color and width to `CCLabelTTF` text but cann't find any way to do.

So How to set border color and width of `CCLabelTTF` text in `cocos2d` ?

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-swift.org/docs/api/Classes/CCLabelTTF.html#//api/name/outlineColor

Comment: what version of cocoS2d are you using ?

Comment: im using cocos2d v3.x

Comment: @iBhavin then follow LearnCocos2D's link . Takes you right to the two methods you are looking for.